# Nginx configuring http_req module

Tags: nginx

Nginx statistic page shows current requests per second from all ip addresses. But for configure http_req module need to specify limit to ONE ip. Is there a way to detect current requests per second from each ip address deal with nginx?

Also will be nice if you tell about how you realize which limit req/sec for your nginx configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To limit request from all clients you need to add

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=login:10m rate=1r/s;
```

to your config file. That code example limits 1request/second for all clients.

Check [this](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/) out for complete tutorial.

Comment: I know it)) But my question is a bit another. How I can determine limit in req/sec? For this, I think need to see current level from one ip, but nginx sttus page explain only req/sec from all ip addresses. Understand me?